# What parts of this HelloWorld assembly code are essential if I were to write the program in assembly?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I have this short hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static const char* msg = "Hello world";

int main(){
    printf("%s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it into the following assembly code with gcc:

```
    .file   "hello_world.c"
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello world"
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   msg, @object
    .size   msg, 4
msg:
    .long   .LC0
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    msg, %eax
    movl    %eax, (%esp)
    call    puts
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

My question is: are all parts of this code essential if I were to write this program in assembly (instead of writing it in C and then compiling to assembly)?  I understand the assembly instructions but there are certain pieces I don't understand.  For instance,  I don't know what .cfi* is, and I'm wondering if I would need to include this to write this program in assembly.

Comment: .cfi are directives for the assembler, not assembly instructions.

Comment: You can remove all the lines starting with `.cfi` and all the ones starting with `.type`, and the one starting with `.file`.  Everything below `.LFE0` can be removed.

Comment: If you were to compile using the GCC option `-fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables` you'd probably see those lines beginning with `.cfi` removed.

Comment: Related: [How to remove “noise” from GCC/clang assembly output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The absolute bare minimum that will work on the platform that this appears to be, is

```
        .globl main
main:
        pushl   $.LC0
        call    puts
        addl    $4, %esp
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
.LC0:
        .string "Hello world"
```

But this breaks a number of [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) requirements.  The minimum for an ABI-compliant program is

```
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        subl    $24, %esp
        pushl   $.LC0
        call    puts
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        addl    $28, %esp
        ret
        .size main, .-main
        .section .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "Hello world"
```

Everything else in your object file is either the compiler not optimizing the code down as tightly as possible, or *optional* annotations to be written to the object file.

The `.cfi_*` directives, in particular, are optional annotations.  They are *necessary* if and only if the function might be on the call stack when a C++ exception is thrown, but they are *useful* in any program from which you might want to extract a stack trace.  If you are going to write nontrivial code by hand in assembly language, it will probably be worth learning how to write them.  Unfortunately, they are very poorly documented; I am not currently finding anything that I think is worth linking to.

The line

```
.section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

is also important to know about if you are writing assembly language by hand; it is another optional annotation, but a valuable one, because what it means is "nothing in this object file requires the stack to be executable."  If all the object files in a program have this annotation, the kernel won't make the stack executable, which improves security a little bit.

(To indicate that you *do* need the stack to be executable, you put `"x"` instead of `""`.  GCC may do this if you use its "nested function" extension.  (Don't do that.))

It is probably worth mentioning that in the "AT&T" assembly syntax used (by default) by GCC and GNU binutils, there are three kinds of lines:  A line
with a single token on it, ending in a colon, is a label.  (I don't remember the rules for what characters can appear in labels.)  A line whose *first* token begins with a dot, and does *not* end in a colon, is some kind of directive to the assembler.  Anything else is an assembly instruction.

Comment: Specifically the ABI for 32-bit code (applying to Ubuntu 14.04) would be the System V i386 ABI which can be found here: https://01.org/sites/default/files/file_attach/intel386-psabi-1.0.pdf

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't care about returning 0, you can go smaller with a tail-call, since main() has args you can replace on the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes A `main` that leaves garbage in the return-value register cannot be said to "work".

Comment: `main(){return puts("Hello World");}` is a valid program.  Its exit status is undefined, but it definitely prints.  (I was hoping that puts would return something specific on success, but the docs just say "a non-negative number", which could be outside the 0..255 range and thus we can't say anything about the program's exit status in the x86 System V ABI.)  I guess I'd better add a caveat to my answer :/

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, I'll concede that such a program doesn't have _undefined behavior_ in the C sense, but I would still contend that not setting the exit status to a deterministic _and meaningful_ value is a serious bug and such a program cannot be said to "work".

Comment: @zwol: yeah, it's a huge caveat that makes it not useful for many purposes, so not something you can do if you don't know all the use-cases ahead of time.  `return printf("Hello World\n")` would have consistent behaviour, with an exit status = string length (except on errors), but that's still generally not useful.  The x86-64 System V version would need to zero %al before the tailcall, though (variadic function with zero FP register args).

Answer (score 4):

**related: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output)**  The `.cfi` directives are not directly useful to you, and the program would work without them.  (It's stack-unwind info needed for exception handling and backtraces, so `-fomit-frame-pointer` can be enabled by default.  And yes, gcc emits this even for C.)

---

As far as the number of asm source lines needed to produce a value Hello World program, obviously we want to use libc functions to do more work for us.

@Zwol's answer has the shortest implementation of your original C code.

**Here's what you could do by hand**, if you don't care about the exit status of your program, just that it prints your string.

```
# Hand-optimized asm, not compiler output
    .globl main            # necessary for the linker to see this symbol
main:
    # main gets two args: argv and argc, so we know we can modify 8 bytes above our return address.
    movl    $.LC0, 4(%esp)     # replace our first arg with the string
    jmp     puts               # tail-call puts.

# you would normally put the string in .rodata, not leave it in .text where the linker will mix it with other functions.
.section .rodata
.LC0:
    .asciz "Hello world"     # asciz zero-terminates
```

The equivalent C (you just asked for the shortest Hello World, not one that had identical semantics):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    return puts("Hello world");
}
```

Its exit status is implementation-defined but it definitely prints.  [`puts(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/puts.3.html) returns "a non-negative number", which could be outside the 0..255 range, so we can't say anything about the program's exit status being 0 / non-zero in Linux (where the process's exit status is the low 8 bits of the integer passed to the `exit_group()` system call (in this case by the CRT startup code that called main()).

---

[Using JMP to implement the tail-call is a standard practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#In_assembly), and commonly used when a function doesn't need to do anything after another function returns.  `puts()` will eventually return to the function that called `main()`, just like if puts() had returned to main() and then main() had returned.  main()'s caller still has to deal with the args it put on the stack for main(), because they're still there (but modified, and we're allowed to do that).

gcc and clang don't generate code that modifies arg-passing space on the stack.  It is perfectly safe and ABI-compliant, though: functions "own" their args on the stack, even if they were `const`.  If you call a function, you can't assume that the args you put on the stack are still there.  To make another call with the same or similar args, you need to store them all again.

Also note that this calls `puts()` with the same stack alignment that we had on entry to `main()`, so again we're ABI-compliant in preserving the 16B alignment required by modern version of the x86-32 aka i386 System V ABI (used by Linux).

`.string` zero-terminates strings, same as `.asciz`, but I had to [look it up to check](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/String.html#String).  I'd recommend just using `.ascii` or `.asciz` to make sure you're clear on whether your data has a terminating byte or not.  (You don't need one if you use it with explicit-length functions like [`write()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html))

---

In the x86-64 System V ABI (and Windows), args are passed in registers.  This makes tail-call optimization a lot easier, because you can rearrange args or pass *more* args (as long as you don't run out of registers).  This makes compilers willing to do it in practice.  (Because as I said, they currently don't like to generate code that modifies the incoming arg space on the stack, even though the ABI is clear that they're allowed to, and compiler generated functions do assume that callees clobber their stack args.)

**clang or gcc -O3 will do this optimization for x86-64, [as you can see on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang390,options:'-std%3Dgnu%2B%2B11+-Wall+-Wextra++-O3+-fverbose-asm',source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B+return+puts(%22Hello+World%22)%3B+%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { return puts("Hello World"); }

# clang -O3 output
main:                               # @main
    movl    $.L.str, %edi
    jmp     puts                    # TAILCALL

 # Godbolt strips out comment-only lines and directives; there's actually a .section .rodata before this
.L.str:
    .asciz  "Hello World"
```

Static data addresses always fit in the low 31 bits of address-space, and executable don't need position-independent code, otherwise the `mov` would be   `lea .LC0(%rip), %rdi`.  (You'll get this from gcc if it was [configured with `--enable-default-pie`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) to make position-independent executables.)

[How to load address of function or label into register in GNU Assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register-in-gnu-assembler)

---

#### Hello World using 32-bit x86 Linux `int 0x80` system calls directly, no libc

**See [Hello, world in assembly language with Linux system calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519222/hello-world-in-assembly-language-with-linux-system-calls)**  My answer there was originally written for SO Docs, then moved here as a place to put it when SO Docs closed down.  It didn't really belong here so I moved it to another question.

---

related: [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).  The smallest binary file you can run that just makes an exit() system call.  That is about minimizing the binary size, not the source size or even just the number of instructions that actually run.