# x86 Assembly registers and mov instruction, and jump offset

Tags: assembly, x86, offset, cpu-registers

I just had a question I couldn't seem to find a decent answer to.
I'm given this code:

```
0020 mov eax, [ebp+0x0c]; value inside = 0x000000ff
0023 mov cl, [ebp+ox08]; value inside- 0x82
0026 cmp al, cl  
0028 jl label             ;label is at address 003c, jl is signed
002a nop
002b
...
003c label:sub al,cl
```

If the value in `[ebp+0x08]` is 0x82 and `ecx` is 0xabcd1234 before executing this code, 
what is the value of `eax` after executing this code?
Would it clear the upper bits so that `ecx` is 0x00000082 or would `ecx` be 0xabcd1282?

Also what's the address from which the offset to the `jl` instruction is calculated?
And how would you determine the value of the offset for the `jl`  instruction?

Isn't the value of `al` greater than `cl`? So wouldn't `jl` **not** jump?

thanks in advance

Comment: `jl` is a *signed* less-than.  You need to interpret your numbers as signed 2's complement.  i.e. `0xff - 256` and `0x82 - 256`, because they both have their sign bit set.

Comment: writing low8 / low16 registers doesn't modify the upper bytes.  This is different from writing 32-bit register, which does zero the full 64-bit register.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register

Comment: You have at least 3 totally separate questions here.  Please don't do that, see [ask].  If you want to see how the assembler calculates the jmp displacement from the end of the instruction, assemble that code and then look at disassembly + hexdump of the machine code bytes.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for links to manuals and guides.  Intel's x86 manuals cover all the details of instruction encoding.

Comment: My bad. These are all questions related to the same code, so I thought it wouldn't make sense to ask three related questions about the same code three separate times. I'm taking a college course where I don't really write code, it is just primarily understanding the concepts. So I'm unaware how to run any of this. However, Thank you for your input Peter.

Comment: If you strip out the addresses, it will assemble with NASM or MASM.  If you have a Linux machine, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39551489/224132 for a Hello World example and the commands to use to build it into an executable.  Put in these instructions with appropriate stores to create the right values in memory (after `mov ebp, esp`), then single-step in GDB.  (example of using gdb at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/a/39551489/224132).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value in `ecx` after loading `cl` is 0xabcd1282.

`cl` (signed -126 / unsigned 130) is less than `al` (signed -1 / unsigned 255) regardless of whether it is treated as signed or unsigned. (In this case, it is treated as signed by `jl`.) So the jump is not taken. Since we don't know what instructions are between 0x2b and 0x3c, there's no way to know what the final values of `eax` and `ecx` are.

The offset for the jump is 0x12 (0x3c - 0x2a, the address of the destination minus the address of the next instruction).