# How do I compile this assembly file with GCC or others?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

I copied a sample assembly code from wiki:

```
.section .data

s0 : .asciz "Processor Brand String: %.48s\n"
err : .asciz "Feature unsupported.\n"

.section .text

.global main
.type main,@function
.align 32
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp,   %rbp
    subq    $48,    %rsp
    pushq   %rbx

    movl    $0x80000000,    %eax
    cpuid

    cmpl    $0x80000004,    %eax
    jl  error

    movl    $0x80000002,    %esi
    movq    %rsp,   %rdi
   ......
    ......
        jmp end

.align 16
error:
    movq    $err,   %rdi
    xorb    %al,    %al
    call    printf

.align 16
end:
    popq    %rbx
    movq    %rbp,   %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    xorl    %eax,   %eax
    ret
```

I replaced main with _start and add syscall at the end, then built it successfully with "as" and "ld". But I thought it should be compiled directly with GCC somehow. So what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gcc -no-pie main.s` for this source which defines a `main`, just like a `.c` that defines a `main`.

`gcc -no-pie -nostartfiles start.s` if you define `_start` (the ELF entry point) yourself.  (Since you're on Linux, glibc can initialize itself via dynamic linker hooks, even if your `_start` doesn't call the glibc init functions.)

To build a static binary without any libraries, `gcc -nostdlib -static start.s`.

Comment: Thank you. The first two does work, but `gcc -nostdlib -static start.s` reports `undefined reference to 'printf'`

Comment: @user2158697: Your program uses printf from libc.  Of course it doesn't link if you tell the linker *not* to link libc.  You can only do that if your program makes system calls directly, like the Hello World in this answer.  [What parts of this HelloWorld assembly code are essential if I were to write the program in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39551489)