# What does call _start in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, ld, glibc

There is a c runtime library, that according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0 is in file `ctr0.o` called to initialize variables before calling main. I have copied it here :

```
.text
    .globl _start
str : .asciz "abcd\n"
_start:
    xor %ebp, %ebp #basePointer == 0
    mov (%rsp), %edi #argc from stack
    lea 8(%rsp), %rsi #pointer to argv
    lea 16(%rsp,%rdi,8), %rdx #pointer to envp
    xor %eax, %eax
    call main
    mov %eax, %edi
    xor %eax, %eax
    call _exit

main:
    lea str(%rip), %rdi
    call puts
```

I have some question regarding the implementation:

1. What is in stack before called `_start` which should be the only entry for linker? I am asking becuase there are expression such as `mov (%rsp), %edi #argc from stack`, where the `_start` is getting value from the stack, but `_start` should not have any `argc` (only `main` does) nor `argv` and `envp`. All these arguments are part of `main` function, not `_start` entry point. So what is in stack before `_start`?
2. This should be designed to provide *initilization* of variables from `.data` or `.bss` segments, but I do not see such initialization of them here. It could be related with the stack, but I do not know how. Before the variables are initialized (which should be in the `ctr0.o`, here), the hold *initial* value and linker reserve space for them (also from that link). In what section of memory type, does gcc hold space for those not-initialized variables?
3. Finally, how to compile this assembly, without stdlib, but requires some of its function (`puts`, `_exit`) in order to work? I have tried `cc -nostdlib foo.s` but

   ```
   /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSKxoPY.o: in function `_start':
   (.text+0x21): undefined reference to `_exit'
   /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccSKxoPY.o: in function `main':
   (.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `puts'
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   ```

(Cannot use `stdlib` otherwise, there would be 2 declaration of `_start` entrypoint).

Comment: 1) see e.g. [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/) or the ELF specification. TL;DR: the operating system places arguments, environment variables and other stuff on the stack 2) `.data` is simply mapped from the file, `.bss` is allocated and zeroed by the loader by the time the entry point is invoked 3) don't do that, even though under circumstances it might work

Comment: You can't call libc functions if you don't link libc.  (Unless you define your own versions, of course.)  There is no magic, they're just labels in front of some instructions in a shared or static library.  (The magic happens when they use the `syscall` instruction to call into kernel code.)

Comment: @PeterCordes can you please give full asnwer or elaborated your comment? Why would I `syscall`, where in my code and what would it added, what is relation between the stack and `syscall`? You just threw some your thoughts without context, but I want the context (full asnwer)

Comment: @Jester "OS places arguments"... What arguments? Is that what `crt0.S` is trying to get from `mov (%rsp), %edi #argc from stack`, and other args from the stack? So OS initialize the stack with some random args, or what is placed there?

Comment: Why would the OS initialize the stack with “some random args”? No, they’re not random, they’re the arguments that the program was invoked with.

Comment: Peter didn’t say you would use syscall. He said that’s what is in the libc code. That was an answer to your third question; it has nothing to do with the stack.

Comment: Regarding question 3, we can give a better answer if you explain what you want to do.

Comment: stack initialization would vary from operating system to operating system and target to target as well as calling convention.  so if per target, per-os per convention the OS inits the stack and not the application and if parameters are passed there then they would be there the rest of the stack could be garbage from power on or from a prior task.  It used to be just garbage but with security today on a modern os you would expect the stack and the rest of the ram allocated to be initialized.  there are environments where it is just random whatever.

Comment: Also understand that crt0 is a specific term and implementation and not generic to the language.  Also the calling convention the compiler happens to use does not in any way have to reflect the operating systems design choices on how to pass the command line.  The boot strap has to conform to the operating system not the other way around.  The operating system design chooses how they want to pass the command line, etc.

Comment: I left a quick comment as a pointer to search for existing Q&As if you wanted to make system calls directly instead of calling libc functions.  (google `site:stackoverflow.com assembly linux syscall`, and see links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  Or on other sites, like https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/04/05/the-definitive-guide-to-linux-system-calls/.  Much has been written about this, you just have go looking.

Comment: Or BTW, you can omit libc's CRT but still link with the library using `glibc -nostartfiles` to link, again as described in some SO Q&As. e.g. [Linking a program using printf with ld?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55314762).  Although to be fair, my first guess at search terms only had that at the bottom of the first page (google `site:stackoverflow.com assembly _start libc`).  Also, I didn't want to write an answer to all 3 parts.  Those are really separate questions, only loosely related.  e.g. part 3 on its own could have easily and quickly been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, when using the same CPU (e.g. an x86-64 CPU), you need different `crt0.S` files for different operating systems.

And you need a different `crt0.S` for programs that are not started using an operating system (such as an operating system itself).

> What is in stack before called `_start` which should be the only entry for linker?

This depends on the operating system. Linux would copy `argc`, the arguments (`argv[n]`) and the environment (`environ[n]`) somewhere on the stack.

The file from your question is intended for an operating system that places `argc` at `rsp+0`, followed by the arguments and the environment.

However, I remember a (32-bit) OS that put `argc` at `esp+0x80` instead of `esp+0`, so this is also possible...

As far as I know, Windows does not put anything on the stack (at least not officially). The corresponding `crt0.S` code must call a function in a DLL file to get the command line arguments.

In the case of a device firmware which is started immediately after the CPU (microcontroller) start, the `crt0.S` code must even set the stack pointer to a valid value first. The memory (including the stack) is often completely uninitialized in this case.

Needless to say that the stack does not contain any useful values in this case.

> This should be designed to provide initilization of variables from `.data` ...

In the case of a software started by an operating system, the operating system will initialize the `.data` section. This means that the `crt0.S` code does not have to do that.

In the case of a microcontroller program (device firmware), the `crt0.S` code has to do this.

Because your file is obviously intended for an operating system, it does not initialize the `.data` section.

> Finally, how to compile this assembly, without stdlib ...

If you want to use the `crt0.S` file from your question, you'll definitely require the `_exit()` function.

And if you want to use the function `puts()` in your code, you'll also need this function.

If you don't use the standard library, you'll have to write these functions yourself:

```
    ...
main:
    lea str(%rip), %rdi
    call puts
    ret

_exit:
    ...

puts:
    ...
```

The exact implementation depends on the operating system you use.

`puts()` will be a bit tricky to implement; `write()` would be easier.

Note:

Please also don't forget the `ret` at the end of the `main()` function; (alternatively you can `jmp` to `puts()` instead of `call`ing it...)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. What is in stack before called `_start` which should be the only entry for linker?

This is defined by the system's ABI. I assume you're on Linux, which uses the System V ABI. In this case, the stack contains `argc`, the `argv` pointers (terminated by a null), the `envp` pointers (terminated by a null), the auxiliary vector (terminated by a null), and finally the values pointed to by the previous pointers.

> `_start` should not have any `argc` (only `main` does) nor `argv` and `envp`. All these arguments are part of `main` function, not `_start` entry point.

That's not right. If `_start` didn't get those, then where else would `main` get them from?

> 2. This should be designed to provide *initilization* of variables from `.data` or `.bss` segments, but I do not see such initialization of them here.

The kernel takes care of that when it maps the process into memory. The only time you'd need code to initialize them would be like in C++, if you had a variable initialized to something that wasn't a compile-time constant.

> In what section of memory type, does gcc hold space for those not-initialized variables?

That's exactly what `.bss` is for.

> 3. Finally, how to compile this assembly, without stdlib, but requires some of its function (`puts`, `_exit`) in order to work?

If you want to use libc functions, then you need to use libc. The right way would be to implement those functions yourself in terms of system calls. For `_exit` it's simple:

```
_exit:
        movl    $60, %eax
        syscall
```

For `puts` it'd be a little bit more complicated, since you have to do `strlen` yourself (hint: `repnz scasb`), handle calling the `write` syscall in a loop, and write a trailing newline, but it should still be perfectly doable.

Just for fun, you could try using `-nostartfiles` instead of `-nostdlib` and then calling the libc functions, but this will probably blow up horribly. Writing the functions yourself is definitely the better approach.